# What is the best way to set up my intranet server for MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, virtualbox, windows-server-2008-r2

I have recently started programming with Asp.Net MVC 4. I have downloaded Visual Studio 2010 from Microsoft DreamSpark and a "Standard" Microsoft Server 2008 R2. Now I installed the Server into a VirtualBox on Promiscuous Network (thus allowing it to talk to my whole network) and next I want to use it to test my applications.

Can you point me to good resources that tell me how to set up the server best for this?

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg703322%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) is a walk-through about creating an intranet site using asp.net MVC, IIS 7 and visual studio 2010.

It worked out for me great.

regards

Comment: Thank you. This is the type of resource that I was looking for but for some reason could not find. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This link is for MVC 3, but it still applies to you. http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3

It includes everything including the Razor engine.

Installation and Help

•Install ASP.NET MVC 3 using the Web Platform Installer (recommended) http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?command=getinstallerredirect&appid=MVC3

•Install ASP.NET MVC 3 using the installer executable http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208140

Comment: It is good for the actual programming side, thank you. However, I need help to set up the server so that I can publish and display the data that I created.

Comment: A basic setup of IIS will surfice, you will notice on one of the tutorials it shows how to install the MVC portion on the server, which you will need

Comment: Installation and Help
 •Install ASP.NET MVC 3 using the Web Platform Installer (recommended) 
•Install ASP.NET MVC 3 using the installer executable

Comment: @KatSeiko, If you didn't want programming advice, why are you asking on SO? You would have better luck on http://serverfault.com/

Comment: @Mike: I am actually programming or working on this. However, I need something to run my stuff. I figured that since you guys are programmers - part of you using MVC - you will definitely know the answer to this question. I am sorry if this thinking offended you.